# connect a postgresql database in node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Here is my code:

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/js/client_world.js', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/js/client_world.js');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log("A user is connected");

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("User disconnected");
});
}); 

http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("Listenng to port 3000")
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="//threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/client_world.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function(){
    loadWorld();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and a third file, client_world,js, where I want to read data from a database.

The first line

```
var {Pool,Client} = require('pg');
```

causes an error.
Is this way to access the DB wrong? Thanks in advance for a hint.

Comment: Which is the error? Post the error message, please

Comment: No error message is displayed.

Comment: No error message is displayed. Client_World.js  shows a cube using a three js function. I also want to access a postgresql database.  As soon as I insert the code for the connection, in the first line "var {Pool,Client} = require('pg');" I only get one blank page.